# Treeview get full path to HDD

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview of a repertory which is into my windows Desktop.
And when I try to get fullpath of a node.
Example:

```
Test\
     t1\
        a
        b
     t2\
        c
        d\
          e
```

When get fullpath of node t2, return : `"Test\t2"` but i would like to have `"C:\Users\Neyoh\Desktop\Test\t2"`.

Do you have any solution ?

Comment: How do you even know it is from the desktop? It could be from some other directory also. Do you store the base directory somewhere? How do you populate the treeview?

Comment: If your treeview show subitem of one folder/drive, just `string RootFolder=@""C:\Users\Neyoh\Desktop\"`

Comment: I have a button "Browse" to select a directory into my computer. And when i selected my directory, the treeview is filled with the repertory selected as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you know the directory of the root node, you can use

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(basePath, nodeValue);
```

This automatically places a backslash between the paths if necessary.